# What actually transpired in the world where Noah grew from, that led to the flood?

Tags: genesis

What actually transpired in the world where Noah grew from, that led to the flood?

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter Six of Genesis the cause of the Flood is described:

**Verses 5-7 (ESV)**

> The LORD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and
>   that every intention of the thoughts of his heart was only evil
>   continually.
>
> And the LORD regretted that he had made man on the earth, and it
>   grieved him to his heart.
>
> So the LORD said, “I will blot out man whom I have created from the
>   face of the land, man and animals and creeping things and birds of the
>   heavens, for I am sorry that I have made them.”

**Verses 11-13 (ESV)**

> Now the earth was corrupt in God’s sight, and the earth was filled
>   with violence.
>
> And God saw the earth, and behold, it was corrupt, for all flesh had
>   corrupted their way on the earth.
>
> And God said to Noah, “I have determined to make an end of all flesh,
>   for the earth is filled with violence through them. Behold, I will
>   destroy them with the earth.

The above verses describe wickedness, evil, corruption, and violence as the catalysts for the Flood.

Comment: Accurate and to the point +1.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we are told is:

> The Lord saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every intention of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually (Gen 6:5 ESV).

Rather than allowing the great wickedness to continue and get even worse (if that were possible!), God determined the merciful thing to do was to wipe out most of humanity, save for Noah and his immediate family.

> But Noah found favor in the eyes of the LORD (Genesis 6:8 NIV).

Comment: Intention of thoughts of hearts was evil continually!  Does this mean that their individual specific sins were Not bearable or repentable and it was only the blurred brain meant to sin continually?

Comment: The answer to this question has wasted much ink.  The simplest way to think about such an evil society is to imaging a place filled with people such as those in Sodom (Gen 19) and Islamic state where ritual raping and beheadings are routine and accepted as normal by all. What could be done?  God made the decision recorded in Genesis.